# Is it possible to click a particular button in a webpage using a batch file program?

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I want to auto login to websites from a batch file.

However, for certain websites, `%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"`, for clicking the login button, does not work. In fact while doing manually, I couldn't find any keyboard button combination that let me press the login button. The only option was to left click on it with the mouse.

Is it possible to write a code for accessing that button and clicking on it using its class name which I can get from "inspect element"?

The batch file that I used is this:

```bash
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
set url = "address of the website"
start CHROME "" %url%
%SendKeys% "my username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "my password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
pause
goto :EOF

@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

Comment: For starters the code that is doing the send keys is jscript. Not Javascript. Embedding the jscript in a batch file is just extra code you don't need.

Comment: Traditionally, you'd use Selenium for this.

Comment: `%url%` has not been defined; you defined `%url %` instead!

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can try it by sending the `Tab` button and then sending the `Enter` key after it